# Maven project folder deletion

Tags: eclipse, maven

I have deleted Maven project folder workspace see below but its not fully deleted

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VNqPg.png)

Comment: If you deleted it with your IDE, you can delete it from view but also delete it on the disk...

Comment: Thank you,Well I deleted from disk also then also it's showing.